# iPad SplitViewController Strange Behaviour

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, popover

I have an Application that uses SplitViewController. When I launch the App and keep the device (or the Simulator) in Portrait Mode, the first time the "DetailView" appears, it doesn't show the popover button, while if I turn the iPad in Landscape Mode, then back to Portrait, the button shows itself correctly.
I've searched around and I discovered that the toolbar where I should present the button is null at the time of first launch.

What should I do?

Comment: I am having same problem with iOS 4.2 ,but there is no issue with iOS 3.2

Comment: That's nice... I hope that on 4.3 no more bugs will be added.

Answer (score 2):

You must set the delegate in your code before you set the window to [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];, so either link the delegate in interface builder or simply call it before you present the window in your application did finish launching method.