# iPad UISplitView Detail Toolbar NULL on Startup

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out a little bug in the iPad half of an app I'm working on.  It's related to the problem in this post:

[iPad SplitViewController Strange Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537827/ipad-splitviewcontroller-strange-behaviour)

Actually, I should say it's exactly the same problem.  However, the only solution given there won't work for me, since my app has a main menu that swaps over to my UISplitViewController's view when the proper button is pressed. The controller and its contained view controllers aren't created until the button press. Thus, I can't set the controller's delegate before calling [window makeKeyAndVisible], since that's done way back when my main menu loads.

Now, I've added some NSLog calls to the delegate's willHideViewController function as follows:

```
NSLog(@"Will hide popover view controller!");
NSLog(@"self=%p",self);
NSLog(@"%@",detailPad.tbToolbar);
```

When I start the app on the iPad in portrait mode, and click to switch over to the split view controller, the delegate's willHideViewController is indeed called, but when it finishes, I'm left with an empty toolbar in my detail view. The strange part about this is that that third NSLog call, which should output info about the detail view controller's toolbar, spits out (null) instead. This is made slightly stranger by the fact that the preceding code sets the toolbar's items, and this code doesn't cause a single exception to be raised, even though the toolbar apparently doesn't exist.

```
[Session started at 2011-02-23 16:16:59 -0500.]  
2011-02-23 16:17:02.626 TEST[33835:207] Will hide popover view controller!  
2011-02-23 16:17:02.628 TEST[33835:207] self=0x5351bc0  
2011-02-23 16:17:02.629 TEST[33835:207] (null)  
2011-02-23 16:17:14.487 TEST[33835:207] Will hide popover view controller!  
2011-02-23 16:17:14.488 TEST[33835:207] self=0x5351bc0  
2011-02-23 16:17:14.490 TEST[33835:207] <UIToolbar: 0x56201a0; frame = (0 0; 703 44); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x5620260>>  
2011-02-23 16:24:52.158 TEST[33835:207] Will hide popover view controller!  
2011-02-23 16:24:52.159 TEST[33835:207] self=0x5351bc0  
2011-02-23 16:24:52.160 TEST[33835:207] <UIToolbar: 0x56201a0; frame = (0 0; 703 44); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x5620260>>
```

As you can see, subsequent logs show that the toolbar is alive and well, and we know the calls are coming from the same object in all cases. These later calls came simply from rotating to landscape and then back to portrait, so it's definitely the same detail view controller as well.

So my question is this: what would cause the toolbar to come back null the first time, but then work properly after doing nothing but rotating the iPad, and what can I do to fix it?

Thanks in Advance,
Ryan

Answer (score 1):

And... I found a workaround.  I had the master view controller set as the split view controller's delegate, which was normally fine. However, the first time willHideViewController is called actually happens BEFORE the detail view has been set up; that's why the toolbar doesn't exist yet. I moved several things over to the detail controller, and made it the delegate instead. Then, in addition to setting the toolbar's items in willHideViewController, I also set them in viewDidLoad.  The detail view controller also hands the popover button and controller to the master view controller, since the master needs to be able to create new detail view controllers and immediately assign them the popover button (I neglected to mention before that the detail view controllers are pushed and popped from a navigation controller).

It ain't pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan

I ran into the exact same problem as you, and this really helped me. I have a variation on your solution that was a little easier. Several key points.

I left the Master as the UISplitViewControllerDelegate, but I added this property on my detail View Controller.h (and synthesized it in .m):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *popoverButton;
```

Then in the calling, master view controller's prepareForSegue, I got the UIBarButtonItem which I stored in that property.

Then in the viewDidLoad of the Detail view controller, I just set that item in the toolbar.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self setSplitViewBarButtonItem:self.popoverButton];}
```

where

```
-(void) setSplitViewBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)splitViewBarButtonItem{
if (_splitViewBarButtonItem!=splitViewBarButtonItem) {
    NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    if (_splitViewBarButtonItem) {
        [toolbarItems removeObject:_splitViewBarButtonItem];
    }
    if (splitViewBarButtonItem) {
        [toolbarItems insertObject:splitViewBarButtonItem atIndex:0];
    }
    self.toolbar.items=toolbarItems;
    _splitViewBarButtonItem = splitViewBarButtonItem;
}
```

}

It feel like a TOTAL hack, but if outlet to self.toolbar in the detail view controller doesnt exist until you're in viewDidLoad, what's a person to do?